# StructureMap MVC, Repository Layer and Console/Class Library

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am using StructureMap for dependency injection and using it successfully with my WebApi application.

The ApiController has the repository defined and in the constructor of this repository is where I am injecting the dependencies, IMapper and DB connection string.

The repository is defined in a separate project (repository layer), which needs to be used by my UI (angular and WebApi) as well as by other solution (in this case a sample console application). I am unable to find out the way to instantiate the repository in my console app with those dependencies passed.

In MVC/WebApi world, the controller creation (factory) and repository bootstrapping happens internally...please correct me if I am wrong.

If we were to use the same repository like this scenario, please give me some ideas. I am pretty new to StructureMap DI.

---

ClientRepository.cs

```
public class ClientRepository : IClientRepository
{
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private string _connectionString;
    private const string CLIENTSCACHE = "clients";
    private MemoryCache _memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public ClientRepository(IMapper mapper, string connectionString)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public List<ClientFileTreeViewModel> GetClients()
    {
       //DB connection
       //transform using Automapper to the viewmodel type and return
    }
    //some other code here
}
```

DefaultRegistry.cs

```
public DefaultRegistry() 
{
        var profiles = from t in typeof(DefaultRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()
                       where typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                       select (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        For<IConfigurationProvider>().Use(config);
        For<IMapper>().Use(mapper);

        RegisterRepositories(mapper);
    }

    private void RegisterRepositories(IMapper mapper)
    {
        For<IClientRepository>().Use<ClientRepository>()
            .Ctor<IMapper>().Is(mapper)
            .Ctor<string>().Is(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeIdentifyDBConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

ClientController.cs

```
public class ClientController : ApiController
{
    IClientRepository _repository;
    public ClientController(IClientRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }
    //some other code
}
```

---

In the console app here now (console app) in Program.cs, I am trying to utilize this repository.

Please help me know how I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Found this wonderful and useful link which helped me understanding on how to implement StructureMap in console application:

http://ardalis.com/using-structuremap-4-in-a-console-app